# Oracle 9.2 pivot distinct value

Tags: oracle, pivot

The pivot function is available from Oracle 11 and i will need similar result using Oracle 9.2.

The main argument is that i need to pivot some values with a distinct result in a table like this:

```
id      col3
1       a
1       b
--
2       a   
2       a
2       b
--
3       a
3       b
3       c
```

My result sould be something like this

```
id      a       b       c
1       1       1       0
2       1       1       0
3       1       1       1
```

To create a "manual" pivot i'm using a case/when but I am not able to understand how to get distinct value.

Right now the query is this:

```
with t as 
    ( select 1 as id, 'a' as col1 from dual union all
      select 1 as id, 'b' from dual union all
      select 2 as id, 'a' from dual union all
      select 2 as id, 'a' from dual union all
      select 2 as id, 'b' from dual union all
      select 3 as id, 'a' from dual union all
      select 3 as id, 'b' from dual union all
      select 3 as id, 'c' from dual
)
select t.id, 
       count(case when t.col1 = 'a' then 1 end) a,
       count(case when t.col1 = 'b' then 1 end) b,
       count(case when t.col1 = 'c' then 1 end) c
```

This produce correct value but obviously it just "count" the total a/b/c value and not the distinct.

thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your need, you can try something like the following; it aggregates by `id` and counts the distinct values of `col3`:

```
with t as 
( select 1 as id, 'a' as col1 from dual union all
  select 1 as id, 'b' from dual union all
  select 2 as id, 'a' from dual union all
  select 2 as id, 'a' from dual union all
  select 2 as id, 'b' from dual union all
  select 3 as id, 'a' from dual union all
  select 3 as id, 'b' from dual union all
  select 3 as id, 'c' from dual
)
select id,
       count(distinct decode (col1, 'a', id, null)) a,
       count(distinct decode (col1, 'b', id, null)) b,
       count(distinct decode (col1, 'c', id, null)) c
from t
group by id
```

Of course the query depends on the number of different values of `col3`, but this is the same problem than `pivot`.